# create java class file in another directory

Tags: java, package

say ~ is my home directory. it got a child directory `java` , which has two child directories `classes` and `sources`. Say I got a file in `~/java/sources/` names Graph.java. I want to compile it such that its class file ends up being in `~/java/classes/`.

Comment: Read the javac docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/javac.html The `-d` option may help.

Answer (score 1):

javac Graph.java -d "~/java/classes/"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use -d parameter with javac to specify the directory you'd like to store the compiled class file.
As Ex:

```
    javac -d <path where to store class file> <your java file to compile>
```

Comment: say I got another source file named A.java in ~/java/sources/ . I want to import the Graph.class in ~/java/classes/. how??